# TimeSpan countdown timer

Tags: c#, timer, countdown, countdowntimer

I am trying to display a countdown in my application with:

```
private TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan()


ts = ts.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
label4.Text = ts.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss");
```

However, it does not display a countdown but the time actually increases. If I remove the `@"hh\:mm\:ss"` part, then I do get a countdown in seconds but not a true countdown. All it does is that it adds a minus sign before the seconds, so it does `-1, -2, -3,` etc... I want it to go say from `10 to 0 so -9, -8, -7,` etc...

How can I have a true countdown in the form of `hh:mm:ss`?

Comment: Good question, and simple answers, +1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Initialize ts to 10: (You are currently initializing it to 0 and decrementing it)

```
private TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)
...
ts = ts.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
label4.Text = ts.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code always subtracts a 1-second timespan from a 0-second timespan.

Maybe you are looking for something like this:

```
public string PrettyTimespan(DateTime finalDate)
{
  return (finalDate - DateTime.Now).ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss");
}
```